# Torque on an arbitrary shaped object having some dipole moment in a uniform electric field

Tags: electrostatics, vectors, torque, dipole-moment

Can anyone show me a proof that the torque on an **arbitrary** shaped object having a dipole moment $\vec{P}$ in a uniform electric field $\vec{E}$ is given by $\mathbf{N}=\mathbf{p} \times \mathbf{E}$.
I couldn't find it in my textbook or on the internet.

Comment: https://byjus.com/physics/torque-on-dipole/

Comment: Consider a dipole as two charges $+q, -q$ joined by a rod, calculate forces on them and the torque on the rod.

Comment: @Bill Watts and Vadim,Thank you but I wanted to find torque for any arbitrary volume charge density.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Assuming constant electric field we've

\begin{align} 
\vec{T} 
&=\int \vec{r} \times(\rho(\vec{r}) \vec{E} d \tau) 
\\ &=\int(\vec{r} \rho(\vec{r}) d \tau \times E) 
\\ &=\left(\int \vec{r} \rho(\vec{r}) d \tau\right) \times \vec{E} 
\\ &=\vec{p} \times \vec{E} 
\end{align}